# Has anyone built Lua 5.2 for OpenWRT?

Tags: lua, openwrt

I'm curious if anyone here has built Lua 5.2 for OpenWRT?

All Google brings up is [this thread disparaging Lua 5.2's new environment system](https://lists.openwrt.org/pipermail/openwrt-devel/2012-January/013572.html), and noting how LuCI won't work with Lua 5.2.

However, I am not at all interested in using LuCI or, for that matter, most of the other Lua code supplied by OpenWRT. Compatibility with LuCI etc. is not an issue.

Therefore my question: Has anyone compiled Lua 5.2 for OpenWRT? Do all the OpenWRT patches apply cleanly? I suspect they don't; at any rate, [the LNUM author has said he does not plan on supporting his patch](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2010-06/msg00002.html).

Basically, I would like to know if building Lua 5.2 is feasible/has been done/sounds doable before I plunge in, lose two weeks to frustration and am then forced to give up.

Comment: Isn't OpenWRT just Linux? Can't you just cross-compile Lua for whatever arch your router is? Lua is written in ANSI C so it shouldn't be hard to port; you shouldn't need patches.

Comment: One wants the OpenWRT patches, though, for performance reasons; particularly LNUM when there's no FPU on-board.

Comment: You desire LNUM, which is not available for 5.2, according to the link? 
(Which is a large patch, 117861 Nov 19 15:26 010-lua-5.1.3-lnum-full-260308.patch)

Answer (score 0):

I build 5.3.2 for OpenWRT Mips32r2. Should be work with 5.2.4 too.
https://github.com/markuman/zsun_fun/blob/master/mips_cross.sh